# Generating user interfaces from Database model

Tags: user-interface, uml, erd

I want to know how to generate UI from a ERD? I also want to learn how to increase efficiency by using UML and ERD.

Comment: What kind of UI? An ERD is an abstract model. How could that produce an UI? In what language? ERD encapsulates no logic to create a UI. Your second question is way too unspecific. I propose reading a book about UML and ERDs. It is not very much about efficiency (in the sense of performance) but about clean design.

Answer (score 0):

I think the question was not well written. 
You can create an UML model and java code from ERD. Having said that the UI and busniess logic need to be coded on the top of this software skeleton.

Some experiences have been to try to model UI but this not related to UML / OMG and all the project seems to have failed !! The need exists but till today no answer :-)